# API request to a local client page

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could you please advise on the following?
Let's assume I have a local html page stored on my local drive "c:\test.html".
If I open it in a browser, it's treated as a GET request to this page, right?

Is it possible to send, for example, POST request to the same local page, with "fetch"?
And inside "c:\test.html" to check if it was requested with POST method, return something?

It would be something like a local-PC API.

Comment: "*I open it in a browser, it's treated as a GET request to this page, right?*" Not exactly, if you're not using a proper HTTP server in the middle.

Comment: Look at the URL when you open the page. It says the protocol. It's a file protocol, not a HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static HTML pages do not have any request capabilities. What's actually happening here is that there is some sort of server that takes your request and responds with the HTML document. You would need to host your own server of some sort that could take and respond to requests. For this, libraries like [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) work well.

Edit: If you are accessing it through a `file://` url, your browser is just reading the file off your drive directly, so you would need some sort of localhosted server.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. When you open a file with your browser, it uses a file protocol, not a HTTP protocol. Look at the URL. You'll see what kind of protocol was used to retrieve the resource.

So no, **you cannot sent a fetch request to a local file**. You have to establish a proper sever in your localhost and let it handle requests. Local files do NOT handle requests. Servers do.